# Rows Get Double Spaced When Pasted To Outlook Email

Tags: html, excel, ajax, outlook, pre

I'm returning a text table via ajax, wrapping it in a pre tag, and writing it to a div. The text table is single spaced. If I copy/paste to Excel, it writes to a single cell, but keeps the single spaced formatting. If I copy/paste that table into an Outlook email, Outlook double spaces the rows. Can anyone tell me why and if so, can you suggest a programmatic workaround? I'd like to keep the single spacing as it does when pasting to Excel.